# iterate through object using values instead of index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of mathematical operators stored as an object.

```
object {0: "-", 1: "*", 2: "/", 3: "+"}  called numOperators
```

I don't know what order the operators will be in, but they need to be execued in the correct order of *, /, +, and -  So when I reassign the above object into another parallel object, I assign the indexes of the above object with the order they need to be executed. Then i have this object:

```
Object {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 3}  called opArray
```

What I want to do is iterate through the object (which could be any length) by looking at the values instead of the indexes.

In summary, I want to iterate all of the values in the order 3, 2, 1, 0.  Look for values of 3 until those are used up, then look for 2, then 1, then finally go through 0. I haven't been able to come up with an efficient way of doing this.  Because mathematical operators need to be done in order, a temporary result value is created and then used for the next iteration.  Eventually, they are all combined into a single result.

This is what I was trying last:

```
var valArray = {0: "3", 1: "8", 2: "4", 3: "8", 4: "2"};
var res=[];//temporary result values ordered by execution
var returnRes=0;
var op=0;
$.each(opArr, function(index, value) {//goes through the values in order    
    if(value==0){
        op = numOperators[index];  //uses the indexes that matches the values
        res[index]=operate(valArr[index], valArr[index+1],op);
        returnRes=res[index];
        console.log(res);
    }
    if(valuei>0){
        op = numOperators[index];
        res[index]=operate(res[index-1], valArr[index+1],op);
        returnRes=res[index];
        console.log(res);
    }
}); 
return(returnRes);
```

I know I may be going about this the completely wrong way, so I'd appreciate some insight on what is an easier way to do this.  Thanks!

To clarify further, I have a valid reason for taking this approach to math and not using eval().  Some of the numbers are derived from variables read in as text and converted.  There could also be text (non-number text) that needs to be concatenated. So I need to get the math and text separated and evaluated differently. I figured an individual approach would be best.

Comment: what is the variable i in your code?

Comment: I had tried a for loop using i, forgot to change it back

Answer (score 0):

The apparent solution seems to be using a for each loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

The other thing you can do and what looks closer to your use case is to write an iterator for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array and sort it by value:

```
var opArray = {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 3};
var array = [];
for (var key in opArray) {
    array.push({
        key: key,
        value: opArray[key]
    });
}

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value < b.value;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
// will print 
//[
//    {"key":"3","value":3},
//    {"key":"0","value":2},
//    {"key":"2","value":1},
//    {"key":"1","value":0}
//]
// So now you can iterate over the array in the correct order
// and access the key and value properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an ordinary array:

```
var numOperators = ["-", "*", "/", "+"];
```

The access is via

```
numOperators.forEach(function (operator) {
    // do something
});
```

possible.

**Example**

> 8*4, result/8, 3-result, result+2

```js
var operators = ['*', '/', '-', '+'],
    functions = {
        '-': function (a, b) { return b - a; }, // spot the changed variables
        '*': function (a, b) { return a * b; },
        '/': function (a, b) { return a / b; },
        '+': function (a, b) { return a + b; }
    },
    valArray = [8, 4, 8, 3, 2];

document.write(valArray.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    return functions[operators[i]](r, a);
}, valArray.shift()));
```

Comment: This only puts together a string. I need to do the correct operation of the math.  The result should be: 1

Comment: 8*4, result/8, 3-result, result+2  Type it in excel and evaluate formula. I think what you've got there is nice and clean and concise but it's not giving the correct result

Comment: but why the changed values (`3 - result`), it makes it difficult to write concise functions and are irritating because of the order.